# "array_agg" function for label in atlas by inserting an expression in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression

I want to put a label on the atlas, to know which points correspond to each student for a data survey. That is to show me for each student a list like this  --> [252, 254, 271]

In the attributes table I have a field "Número" which contains the code of each point, and a field "Alumnos" which contains the code for each student.

I have written the following code:

array_agg("Número","Alumnos")

to generate a list of "Número", grouped by "Alumno"

In the attached image, I show the code and the preview at the bottom that is correct. However, nothing is loaded on the atlas :(

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to convert it to a string object:

`array_to_string(array_agg("Número","Alumnos"))`

Comment: This worked perfectly!!! Thank you very much!!